# in running single node kaa server becuse It throws exception below

Tags: java, smtp, kaa

**Unexpected service error occurred: Failed to send email with temporary password. Please, check outgoing email settings. See server logs for details.**

log file contains

> DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javamail.providers (No such file or
>   directory) DEBUG: !anyLoaded DEBUG: not loading resource:
>   /META-INF/jav

Comment: Help me out in getting rid of this question

Comment: Have you configured the mail settings in admin UI? What is the version of kaa ?

Comment: version is :Kaa IoT plaform 0.9.0 and I have used institute SMTP settings in Outgoing email settings. Is there any way to skip SMTP settings @Pete

Comment: We need a proper SMTP setting to sent out mails(which contains temporary password to login) on creating users. You configure **Postfix** SMTP server in Ubuntu if required. Also you may see the mail body in Kaa server logs when you create a new user from the admin UI.